# Windows disk partiton: Cannot shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files are located

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs, nvme

As you can see from the title, im not able to shrink my C drive NTFS partition (My Windows 11) partition.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/flz4j.png]

Here are something i tried to solve it:

1. Disable hibernation through `powercfg/h off`
2. Disable virtual memory and set to no paging file
3. Disable system protection
4. Defragment the disk with `Defragment and Optimize Disk`
5. After defrag, i checked the event viewer log and filter `defrag`. The first event(latest) shown successful.

After all of them i restarted my pc

Comment: What does it say in the log?

Comment: A third-party defragmenter might do better, especially one that can run at boot. See this [random link](https://www.lifewire.com/free-defrag-software-tools-2619172). Take backups.

Comment: You need to defrag it on another pc or using live usb booted OS, or similar. You wont be able to "move" file(s) to another sector if(and they are) its used by system. After defragment is done, reset and enter your OS as usual, and try to resize partition(you can try resize on live OS, but not advisable).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Windows install USB stick (any Win10/Win11 version will work).
2. Boot from the USB stick.
3. At the "Welcome to Windows Setup" screen, press Shift-F10.
4. In the "Command Prompt" window, run `diskpart`.
5. In Diskpart, run `list disk` to find your disk and `sel disk XXX` to select it.
6. Run `list part` to find your C:\ partition and `sel part XXX` to select it.
7. Run `shrink querymax` to check how much the volume can be shrunk.
8. Run `shrink desired=MMM minimum=MMM` to shrink it by the specified number of megabytes.
9. Exit Diskpart, run `wpeutil reboot`, remove USB stick.